# CentOS SSH broken pipe freeze

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, broken-pipe

When I'm connected via SSH to a CentOS box that was recently set up, if I am idle for too long I will become disconnected from the server. There is a long (roughly 30 seconds) freeze of the terminal and then finally I get "Write failed: Broken pipe".

I'm fine with the broken pipe, I have no problem with being disconnected if I'm not active. It is annoying to have to wait for that lag before I get to that point though.

Is there some way to address that delay?

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Not general computing issues. Your question may be appropriate for other Stackexchange sites such as [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Do check their help pages first before posting.

Comment: That's an odd stance considering how many broken pipe-related questions there are in Stackoverflow. Just looking at the Related section below, the list is full of them and none of them are put on hold.

Comment: Just because other off topic questions have been let through doesn't change the definition of what questions Stackoverflow is meant for. It's a community moderated site so there's bound to be variability across it. But read the SO help pages and decide for yourself whether your question falls within the category of "programming related" as defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this in /etc/ssh/ssh_config on Centos:
Edit the following settings

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

This is how often, in seconds, it should send a keepalive message to the server.

You could set either ServerAliveInterval in /etc/ssh/ssh_config of the client machine or ClientAliveInterval in /etc/ssh/sshd_config of the server machine.

Try lowering the interval if you keep getting the error

Comment: You may also state that `ServerAliveCountMax` has a default value of `3`. Your solution then will terminate connection after `360 seconds` or `10 minutes` of unresponsiveness.

Comment: Doesn't this just keep the connection alive longer? Like I said, I have no problem with the connection dying after a while, I'd just like to get rid of the freezing when it does it.

Comment: Lowering it will allow your client to keep checking in more frequently in the background so it doesn't time out , so you wouldn't have to see the freezing